# Is that possible to embed KnowledgeHome tab in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, iframe

I tried with iframe tag and passed knowledge tab url in src attribute but it does not work, when the page is run you don't see anything.

```
<apex:iframe src="/_ui/knowledge/ui/KnowledgeHome"/>
```

Error:

> Refused to display
>   https://XXXX.salesforce.com/_ui/knowledge/ui/KnowledgeHome  in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one feature called "Clickjack Protection" which is by default enabled in Salesforce after Winter 16 (not sure about release though). If this feature is enabled in Salesforce, you won't be able to iframe your own Salesforce org (standard) pages in Visualforce pages. There is more information present on this feature on Salesforce site, please refer following link,

**Link:** https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_clickjack_with_headers_disabled.htm

Let me know if you need any additional info and mark answer correct if this solves your problem.

Comment: what exactly do i need to change or enable? i have tried enabling this checkbox one at a time `Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers
Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled ` but i'm still seeing the error which I posted in my question,

Comment: To disable "ClickJack" protection, you will need to log a case to Salesforce. We are not allowed by Salesforce to disable that security feature.  We can only enable it but if we want to disable, then we will need to ask Salesforce to disable it for our org.